# using wget to download all data from a webpage

Tags: wget

I need to be able to download just the data from the page into a text file to parse later with a different program.  I've used this syntax with other sites and works perfect, but I've run into a program with one web site.

Here's the site and the syntax I'm using:

WGET.EXE http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/AAAAX/f?t=AAAAX -O AAAAX.TXT --no-check-certificate -owebdata/logfile.txt

This downloads the page but key data I need to see is not there.  For example:
Expenses Turnover and status data is not there

I know the script is using a sub-program to produce the data but I know WGET is capable of just downloading the output to a file, I'm just unclear what flag or option to set to make it do it

Answer (score 1):

The expenses and turnover and other status data are set using javascript on the page. As far as i know, you cannot wget that as it is generated on the client side when javascript runs on the browser.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Is there not a way for WGET to view all data presented and save to file.  Basically like video capture?

Comment: Yes, there are ways... but before that please reconsider web-scraping because it is considered illegal on some sites. Please read their TOS and then proceed. See if they have an API which you can use.
Coming back to the alternative way, I think you need to try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: I wouldn't think either of the three sites I'm using this on would mind, beings I invest my money with all three.  The data from the site is basically used just like the fund screener they provide free, but I have found to be inadequate for my needs.  But I do understand fully your point.  I will check out your option...Thanks